# Method to check if solutions of given differential equation are identically zero or bounded.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given a differential equation
 $y'+ 2y = 0$. Then which of the following options is correct one?

A) every solution is identically zero.

B) all solutions are unbounded.

C) every solution tends to zero as x tends to infinity.

D) no solution tends to zero as x tends to infinity.

I havw no idea how to check if solutions are unbounded or identically zero. Even if checking these things is not needed to answer this problem, I have a request to get me know the method.

Options $C$ & $D $ are probably find out by using limiting values of solution.

When I solved the given D.E using variable seperable form , I found the solution to be

$yc = 2x$ (if I am not wrong)..
I dont have idea to analyse further

Extremly sorry fir the stupidiest mistake done. I have corrected the options. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your solution again, it should be $y=Ae^{-2x}$. So $(C)$ seem to be correct. $(B)$ doesn't hold when $A=0$.

Identically zero means : $y(x)=0\;\forall x$

Unbounded means: Given $M>0,\exists x:|y(x)|>M$

To prove unboundedness here take look at the region $x<0$.

Comment: I am extremly sorry for mistake in the last two options. Kindly note and help me to get the answer.